# How i can return empty array if user select a specific element in select, using reactive form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, ng-zorro-antd

my select allows you to enter several employees. I also have an option that allows you to select all employees.
I would like that when this option is selected an empty array is returned to me as value, instead I am still returned an array with an empty string or an empty array inside.

```
<nz-select
            class="text-xl text-white hover:text-gray-1 w-full"
            nzMode="multiple"
            nzBorderless
            [nzDropdownMatchSelectWidth]="false"
            [nzPlaceHolder]="t('select_clients')"
            [nzOptionOverflowSize]="5"
            [formControlName]="mf.CLIENTS_FIELD"
          >
            <nz-option nzValue="" [nzLabel]="t('broadcast')"> </nz-option>

            <nz-option
              *ngFor="let client of clients$ | async"
              [nzValue]="client.id"
              [nzLabel]="client.name + ' - ' + client.language.toUpperCase()"
            ></nz-option>
          </nz-select>
```

```
this.mf.clientsControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(value);
      if (value.includes('') && value.length > 1) {
        if (value.indexOf('') === value.length - 1) {
          value = value.filter((val) => val === '');
        } else {
          value = value.filter((val) => val !== '');
        }
      }
      console.log(value);

      this.mf.clientsControl.patchValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    });
  }
```

```
messageForm: FormGroup;

this.messageForm = this.fb.group({
      [this.TITLE_FIELD]: ['', Validators.required],
      [this.BODY_FIELD]: ['', Validators.required],
      [this.DATE_FIELD]: [null, Validators.required],
      [this.CLIENTS_FIELD]: [[], Validators.required],
    });
  get clientsControl() {
    return this.messageForm.get(this.CLIENTS_FIELD) as FormGroup;
  }
```

At present if the user selects "select all", he returns me [''].
I would like instead to be returned an empty array.

Comment: What is `['']` ?  is it an array containing only an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array before returning like:

```js
[''].filter(element => Boolean(element)); // []
```

An empty array is considered to be `falsy` and therefore filtered out. Any other string would pass.

For your scenario it would look like:

```js
this.mf.clientsControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {

      if (value.includes('') && value.length > 1) {
        if (value.indexOf('') === value.length - 1) {
          value = value.filter((val) => val === '');
        } else {
          value = value.filter((val) => val !== '');
        }
      }
      
      // Here it filters the empty strings out
      const nextValue = value.filter((val) => Boolean(val));
      this.mf.clientsControl.patchValue(nextValue, { emitEvent: false });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have to process it even before it is sent to the server.
So I would need to send it to the already empty pathvalue, but if I empty the array the select label disappears. So i must edit it in reactiv form control

Comment: Yes, but in this solution, i don't see "select all" option selected

Comment: Why don't just simply set a value for this "all" option and then do it conditionally.

Like, you can send an empty array, when you know that the array contains this `all` option.

Comment: because i will have [ [] ] in this mode

Comment: No you won't if the option for `select all` has a value.

Comment: ok, but i need that in case the "select all" option is checked, i get an empty array.
I don't want to get either [null], [''] or [[]].

Comment: As I said. Setting a value to the `select all` should give you something like `['all']` or whatever you defined.

Comment: yes, but i don't want ['all'] or similar... i want []

Comment: But you can filter that. value.filter(val => !val.includes('all')) or you can check on that `if (value.includes('')) { return []; }`

Comment: i can't do this by design specification.
I probably have to manage several controls in the reactiveForm, one that sends the data and one that displays it.